# Verify if my code is much better this way to be written

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I just went through to this case:

I am trying to keep my code simple and clean. It feels I went overboard with this. and it seems to be to lengthy. Is there a short or better version to implement this ? Not even sure if it is the correct answer.

Thank you and I hope someone guide me if it is correct or show me better way to implement this

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this community isn't intended to do reviews of working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your dataset by given sample Country and then check if given Broker [is in](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) your dataset.

Example:

```
sample_country = sample_df['Account Country'].values
sample_broker = sample_df['Broker'].values

if sample_broker.isin(dataset.loc[dataset['Country'] == sample_country], 'Broker'):
   print(sample_country[0], "Broker")
else:
   print('brokers aren’t settled with the appropriate brokers')
```

Edited for the case of more than one samples in `sample_df`:

```
for i in range(len(sample_broker)):
   if sample_broker[i].isin(dataset.loc[dataset['Country'] == sample_country[i]], 'Broker'):
      print(sample_country[i], "Broker")
   else:
      print('brokers aren’t settled with the appropriate brokers')
```

Comment: It is more than one row, How to create the loop? when there is more than one row

Comment: for i in  MaskIsInBroker:
    if sample_broker == MaskIsInBroker.all():
        print(sample_country[i], "Broker")
else:
    print('Not settled with the appropriate brokers') 
I did it like that, still there is an error

Comment: You can iterate over sample_country and sample_broker values accordingly.

Comment: I am still struggling with it. Can edit your answer and show me please?

Comment: It's edited right now but I am not sure if this works on your case @ZaidZaid

Comment: Thank you so much
it says 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'

Comment: You should change the type to a pandas.Series